# Is there a way to get a non-global clone of scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global?

Tags: scala, concurrency, threadpool, executorservice, fork-join

I'm looking for a non-global instance of the `ForkJoinPool` so that I'd get all the great default parallelism and execution semantics of the global instance with the ability to control the life cycle of the pool.

I peeked into the source code of `scala.concurrent` and `scala.concurrent.impl,` and, sadly, it looks like all of the code that's creating the default instance is `private[scala.concurrent]`, and there's no indirect way to call the code either.

I can only get a fresh instance of the `ExecutionContext` with default settings using `ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(null)`, but there's no way to grab ahold of the underlying `ForkJoinPool`. Nor is there a way to shut down an `ExecutionContext` directly.

Am I doing something esoteric that I shouldn't be doing? Because to me it seems like a natural thing to want: default semantics/configuration of something without the global'ness of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a question of access but of shape. The tail of the elephant:

```
scala> type ECI = { def createExecutorService: ExecutorService }
defined type alias ECI

scala> val fjp = ExecutionContext.global.asInstanceOf[ECI].createExecutorService
fjp: java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService = scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool@606dff1[Running, parallelism = 8, size = 0, active = 0, running = 0, steals = 0, tasks = 0, submissions = 0]
```

or shapelessly:

```
scala> import shapeless.syntax.typeable._
import shapeless.syntax.typeable._

scala> val fjp = concurrent.ExecutionContext.global.cast[ECI] map (_.createExecutorService) getOrElse ???
fcp: java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService = scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool@45c26421[Running, parallelism = 8, size = 0, active = 0, running = 0, steals = 0, tasks = 0, submissions = 0]
```

and then

```
scala> val eces = ExecutionContext fromExecutorService fjp
eces: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContextExecutorService = scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$$anon$1@1df3794c

scala> eces.shutdown
```

Comment: don't know how I missed the bit that it's that simple... thanks a bunch! :)

Answer (score 3):

The good thing about `private[path.to.package]` is that you can work around it simply by *pretending to be inside that package*:

```
package scala.concurrent

import java.util.concurrent.Executor

object Foo {
  implicit lazy val myGlobalExecutionContext: ExecutionContextExecutor =
    impl.ExecutionContextImpl.fromExecutor(null: Executor)
}
```

However, be advised that if you do this, you are not in the realm of **public API** anymore and will have to deal with certain incompatibilities when you change the scala version.

Comment: OK, that's obvious; didn't really think of that before :) by the way, your code still doesn't get the default pool itself, just the default execution context, but I guess I could adapt it to get the underlying pool.

Comment: I also did not know about this *feature* a few hours ago until I watched the latest [scalawags](http://scalawags.tv/) episodes in which Josh Suereth explains why it exists and how it can be ridiculously helpful.

Comment: I'm not accepting/upvoting just yet to see if I can get some other opinions out of this; if not, the rep is yours.